# Restrict build agent to specific branches

Tags: teamcity

In teamcity is it possible to restrict build agents to specific branches?

There are some interdependencies between my build configurations and I need the same build agent to build the same branch. If left to its own devices teamcity sometimes activates a new build agent for something later in the chain. This then fails.

What I'd like to do (at least until we can perhaps improve our build configurations to make them independent (artifacts?)) is assign one build agent to a branch. That would at least get things moving.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use GIT as VCS? How are the Branches specified in your build configs?

Comment: Yes, git. The branches aren't specifically mentioned in the build configs except in the triggers. The problem is that say Step 3 is dependent on the same agent having done Step 2, so if Teamcity decides to use a different agent for Step 3 to Step 2 it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Alina already stated, you should not use the same configuration for multible "long-life" branches.

It´s very simple to create a build config for each branch:

1. Go to your existing Build Configuration
2. Introduce a `%Branch%` Parameter and adjust checkout rules etc.
3. Use "Extract Template" to create a template out of it
4. Create one configuration for each branch (dev / int / release) from
   the template, all you need to change there is the `%Branch%` Parameter

That´s where TeamCity shines imo.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like misuse of Feature Branches in TeamCity. Feature branches are for short-lived branches. For long-lived branches it's recommended to create separate build configurations and set up agent requirements per build configuration.

Comment: This isn't about building feature branches, but more around release branches vs main integration branch (develop branch). Everything in develop branch gets built, then also any release branches get built. But they do use the same build configurations. Do I really need to duplicate the configurations? I appreciate that our set up is sub-optimal right now, but was hoping that by simply restricting a build agent to release branches and one to develop branch that would improve things.

Comment: You can use [build configuration templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Configuration+Template) and [build parameters](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration#DefiningandUsingBuildParametersinBuildConfiguration-UsingBuildParametersinBuildConfigurationSettings) to simplify the setup.

Comment: Thanks. templates should help.